# NodeJS mysql connection.query callback not logging results to console?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Trying to use the mySQL npm package to connect to a database and print the results of queries.
Why do the console.log() statements within con.connect() and con.query() not print 'connected!' or the results of the query to the console?

The console.log("we here now") gets executed and the program does not exit.
If I supply a wrong password/host the error within con.connect() does get thrown but when the connection is established, "connected!" isn't printed.
What am I missing?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'host',
    port: 'port',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass'
});


con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("connected!");
    con.query("SELECT 1 as solution", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
});

console.log("we here now");

con.end();
```

Comment: mention port no 3306

Comment: I've just removed the correct host/port from this code. I am supplying the correct params while running the script.

Answer (score 0):

1- Have you correctly changed these 4 variable

host: 'host',
port: 'port',
user: 'user',
password: 'pass'

2- Make sure that your mysql DB server is running

3- Verify your SQL SELECT Query, what is 1 and from which table ?
and make sure that the DB is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in server.js file

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
const util = require('util');

        const mysqlconnection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: '10.0.1.117', //Change this IP
            user: 'john',
            password: 'password',
            database: 'customers_db',
            port: 3306,
            multipleStatements: true,
        });
          
      

const db1 = mysqlconnection;
const query = util.promisify(db1.query).bind(db1);


async function connectMySql(callback) {
    mysqlconnection.connect(async function (err, client) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error connecting: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        let myquery1 = "SELECT * FROM users";
        var newRecords = [];
        newRecords = await query(myquery1)
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
        console.log(newRecords)
    });
};

connectMySql();
```

This gives output as

```
> [ RowDataPacket {
>     UserId: 101212,
>     LoginName: 'user1233',
>     RoleName: user',
>     C7: '2021-07-28 11:29:28' } ]
```

Comment: Check the updated answer. This works in server.js file

Answer (score 0):

So a few things.

First, a slight refactor. Move the `connection.query` to the same scope as the `connect` invocation.

Make sure you set the connection config of course:

```js
const mysql      = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'BE_SURE_TO_SET_ME',
  user     : 'BE_SURE_TO_SET_ME',
  password : 'BE_SURE_TO_SET_ME',
  database : 'BE_SURE_TO_SET_ME'
});

connection.connect(function(error){
  if (error) {
    console.error('❌ Query failed: ', error);
    throw error;
  }
  console.log('✅ Connection successful');
});

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('❌ Query failed: ', error);
    throw error;
  }
  console.log('✅ Query successful. Results: ', {results});
});

connection.end();
```

Secondly, JS is async by nature, so the reason `console.log("we here now");` fires is because it is in the same scope as `connect`. The JS engine won't wait until the connect callback is called, it just moves to the next statement. So there's a race condition - it may (or may not) be executed on the process tick before the connect function callback throws an error.

Accordingly, I have added `console.log` and `console.error` statements in the callbacks where they occur. This will give you better feedback. (ps. better to use a logger like `winston`)

Comment: I tried this and the console.log('Connection successful'); and the console.log('Query succesful. Results: ', {results}); do not get executed. A console.log() after the connection.query() and before connection.end() does get invoked though. Why?

Comment: Can you post what gets printed out to your console (including the errors)